# Programatically override token symbol with MetaMask wallet_watchAsset

Tags: metamask

MetaMask does not allow to add custom tokens with a symbol of more than 11 characters. In order to do so, users need to customise the symbol manually and add it.

However, we would like to programatically change the symbol via the [wallet_watchAsset](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/wallet_watchasset/) API. However, when we try to simply change the symbol to be cut off at less than 11 characters we receive the following error:

> The symbol in the request (SOME_TOKEN) does not match the symbol in the contract (SOME_TOKEN_SYMBOL)

Although it is now 9 characters long. Is there any way to programatically achieve the same as if a user would override the symbol manually?

Comment: When importing tokens manually in MetaMask, the application may be more lenient with symbol matching, allowing for slight discrepancies or variations in symbol naming. However, when using the `wallet_watchAsset` API programmatically, MetaMask performs stricter checks to ensure that the provided symbol matches exactly with the symbol defined in the token contract.

Comment: If you have control over the token contract, you could update the symbol directly in the contract to be within the **11-character** limit. If modifying the original token contract is not an option (e.g., it's a widely-used token), you could create a **proxy** contract that interacts with the original token contract. In the proxy contract, you can override the `symbol()` function to return a truncated symbol that fits within MetaMask's limit.

Comment: @SYEDASADKAZMI thanks for your response. If MetaMask is more lenient with the symbol matching when adding a renamed token, there should be a way to achieve the same thing programatically, right? Is there a flag that gets send with it when done manually?

Comment: Actually, I tried monitoring the network logs while adding the token manually (on the MetaMask website instead of extension), but seems like they've hidden all the API calls being made on their website for security purposes. I think you can try contacting the MetaMask support, they might help you out with this.

Comment: @SYEDASADKAZMI thanks for the effort. Cross posting the thread I have created on their support forum for visibility: https://community.metamask.io/t/programatically-override-token-symbol-with-metamask-wallet-watchasset/28504